# Exiftool geotag on untag pictures

Tags: exiftool, geotagging

I will use `exiftool` for geotagging many pictures using a `kml` file. Is there any option on command line for tagging only pictures without any existing geotag? I do not find any information about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply check to see if there already was a Latitude (or Longitude) by adding `-if "not $GPSLatitude"` to your command.

Change double quotes to single quotes if you're on Mac/Linux.

Another option would be to instead add `-wm cg`.  That means that exiftool will not try to overwrite tags that already have data.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.